# R Shiny Warning in output$out1 <- renderText({ : Coercing LHS to a list

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app where I pass in some user input data to a regression model that predicts a value. I have an actionButton that tells the app to update the prediction and output to a textOutput through renderText function.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
```

a bunch of selectInput statements

```
actionButton("run", "Estimate Hours"),
textOutput("out1")
)
```

In the server section the code looks like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

observeEvent(input$run, {
```

.. get model prediction based on input data

```
output$out1 <- renderText({

    paste("prediction is ", round(pred))
})
```

when I run this nothing is output to out1. Instead there is a warning that says Warning in output$out1 <- renderText({ : Coercing LHS to a list.

But I checked pred and it is a numerical variable, not LHS. What does this warning mean and why is there nothing in the output?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/pHgBPp3W7yg

Comment: I've seen this post before. It wasn't helpful.

Comment: The warning means that the object `òutput` was either changed or masked before `output$out1 <- ` was called such that the list operator `$` is not defined. Try to put `message(class(output))` just before the assignment and see what class `output` has.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I re-ran my app today without making any changes and for some reason it works fine now and I don't get the warning anymore. It's strange. If I found the reason for the warning I'll make a post here.

Comment: Okay, I found out why I was getting the warning.There was a name collision. I had another variable named "output" that caused the shiny object "output" to be overwritten before it was used  I just renamed that variable to something else and now the app works fine. Thanks to Gregor for the hint.